# Possible to only run code block inside for loop once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the loop to find whole table columns containing cells with a certain class and it works fine for applying class and the other stuff below. The only problem is that I would also like to output the value of the cells once. Is this possible somehow?

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        var col = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ').check').length;  
        if (col == 5) {
            $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);
            var column = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
            column.addClass("bingo", 2000);  
            var text = column.text().toUpperCase(); 
            $("#textout").append(text + "!!");         
        }
    }
});
```

Update:

```
  $('td:first-child').each(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var col = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ').check').length;
    var column = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
    if (col == 5) {
    $( ".bingocl" ).fadeIn(2000);
    column.addClass("bingo", 2000);             

column.each(function() {
  $("#textout").append($(this).html() + " ");
});
break;
      }
    }
});
```

function in it's entirety:

```
var main = function() {

  //Styling the rows 
  $(".tabell tbody").find("tr").each(function(idx) {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find("td").length == row.find("td.check").length) {
      row.addClass("bingo");
      $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);
      var text = row.find("td").text().toUpperCase();
      $("#textout").append(text + "!!");
    }
  });

  //styling cols
  $('td:first-child').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      var col = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ').check').length;
      if (col == 5) {
        $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);
        var column = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        column.addClass("bingo", 2000);
        var text = column.text().toUpperCase();
        $("#textout").append(text + "!!");
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: `that I would also like to output the value of the cells, once. Is this possible somehow?` where are you outputting the values? Its not clear in the code

Comment: Yea I realised, added now

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle Here it is in live environment, lot's of PHP involved so can't use fiddle. http://socialsiberia.com/aftonbladet/bingo.php
Basically a bingo where I'd like to use jquery do style the rows and cols when it contains certain words, and (which this post is about) output the values of the cells.

Comment: I added an answer in case you haven't already solved your issue. I think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you already have access to your winning row/column (you add a `bingo` class to them), you can access each individual element to output it's value.

Your code becomes:

```
var main = function() {

  //Styling the rows 
  $(".tabell tbody").find("tr").each(function(idx) {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find("td").length == row.find("td.check").length) {
      row.addClass("bingo");
      $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);

      // Iterate your row elements
      row.each(function(){document.write($(this).html() + " ");});
    }
  });

  //styling cols
  //$('td:first-child').each(function() { <- remove this
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      var col = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ').check').length;
      if (col == 5) {
        $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);
        var column = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        column.addClass("bingo", 2000);

        // Iterate your column elements
        column.each(function(){document.write($(this).html() + " ");});

        break;
      }
    }
  //}); <- remove this
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

**Live example**

```js
var column = $(".selected_column");
var row = $(".selected_row");

column.addClass("bingo");
row.addClass("bingo");

column.each(function() {
  $("#textout").append($(this).html() + " ");
});

row.each(function() {
  $("#textout").append($(this).html() + " ");
});
```

```css
.selected_column {
  background: blue;
}
.selected_row {
  background: yellow;
}
.selected_column.selected_row {
  background: green;
}
.bingo {
  border: 2px solid lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="selected_column">B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F</td>
    <td class="selected_column">G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>J</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td class="selected_column">L</td>
    <td>M</td>
    <td>N</td>
    <td>O</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="selected_row">P</td>
    <td class="selected_column selected_row">Q</td>
    <td class="selected_row">R</td>
    <td class="selected_row">S</td>
    <td class="selected_row">T</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>U</td>
    <td class="selected_column">V</td>
    <td>W</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="textout">#textout : </p>
```

Comment: Looks really good, my ONLY concern is document write. Since the text is posted at the same page as the table (which is built in a PHP function) Is it possible to achieve the same this but specify in which div the text is displayed?

Comment: Yes ofc. See my edit. Use `$("#textout").append(...)` just like you did in your question.

Comment: I tried that but it gets output 5 times, since it's called within the for loop. That's the iffy thing with all this..

Comment: Did you add the `break` statement ?

Comment: Yes, see update in original post. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: `$('td:first-child').each(...)` has nothing to do here. The problem isn't your `for` loop. `$('td:first-child').each(...)` multiplies your `for` loop 5 times (there are 5 *first-child* `td`'s in your table). So just remove it :) see my edit. Hopefully this will sort the issue.

Comment: Sorry for a late response, but this solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do `column.html();` to get the cell content

Answer (score 0):

You could always try with `break`.
Link: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use break:

```
$('td:first-child').each(function() {
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var col = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ').check').length;  
    if (col == 5) {
        $(".bingocl").fadeIn(2000);
        var column = $('.tabell tr').find('td:nth-child(' + i + ')');
        column.addClass("bingo", 2000);  
        var text = column.text().toUpperCase(); 
        $("#textout").append(text + "!!");   
        break;      
    }
}
});
```

Comment: With break it didn't output any text at all unfortunately

Comment: You can also output any text before breaking the loop and you can also store it into any global variable aur json  , after outputing that text you may break it

Comment: Edit: it does output text, but five times, just as without break;